# Segment fault for array C program

Tags: c

For some reason I am getting a segment fault at the line let[i] = all(4,4,'a','z'); I can't figure out why. I'm trying to put aaaa - zzzz in an array & then compare the values one by one to an encrypted password. Any advice would help. Thanks. Ive given two snippets of my code that are giving the issue.

```
 char* all(int a, int n,char begin, char end){
   int i, j;
   int k = 0;
   char *c = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));

   char msg[] = "";
   k = strlen(msg);
   for(i = a; i <= n; i++)
   {
      for(j=0;j<i;j++) c[j]=begin;
      c[i]=0;
      do {
         for(int g = 0; g < k; g++) 
            msg[g] = *c;
      } while(inc(c,begin,end));
   } 
   return c;
   free(c);
}   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char *result;
   char **let;

   int f = open("pass.txt", O_RDONLY);
   if (f < 0) 
      return 0;
   char buf[1024];
   while (my_fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) 
   {
      int i = 0;
            let[i] = all(4,4,'a','z');

      result = crypt(argv[i+1], buf);
      i++;
      int ok = strcmp (result, buf) == 0;

      return ok ? 0 : 1;

   }
   free(let);
   close(f);
}
```

Full program can be found here:

http://pastie.org/10035996

Comment: For some reason you seem to dereference an uninitialized pointer. Hint: let[i]. `char msg[] = ""` also declares an array of size 1 and then you write past that.

Comment: So I should just have let[i] and not declare it to begin with? Sorry. I'm new to this.

Comment: It's not _segment_, it's _segmentation_ fault.

Answer (score 0):

You want `let` to be an array of (pointers to individual) strings. You are allocating storage space for the strings, but not for the array itself. So, either declare:

```
char *let[MAX_STRINGS];
```

if you have a maximum number of strings known at compile time, or allocate it dynamically:

```
let = malloc (sizeof (char *) * whatever_number);
```

In both cases you must take care not to exceed the allocate quantity during the input phase. If you want to be able to handle any possible quantity of input strings you will have to change your data structure, maybe to a linked list, but I guess that's an advanced topic for you at the moment.

Also note that the `free(let)` you have right now in your code will only free memory for the array itself, but you will also need to free the individual strings before that. Basically you have to perform a `free()` for every `malloc()` you have in your code.

Comment: I changed my let to char **let =malloc(sizeof(char*)*10) but I'm still getting the segment fault? I think it has to do with my let[i] = all(4,4,'a','z') and my    char *c = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
@sukkopera

Comment: Would you explain exactly what the intended meaning of the `a` and `n` parameters to `let()` is? On a side note, the `free()` after `return` makes no sense, remove it. It is never executed anyway.

Comment: the a parameter is how many letters it starts with & the n parameter is how many letters it ends with. For example if I did all(1,4,'a','f'); it would go from a, b, c, d, ... ffff

Comment: full program was added to the question.

Comment: Then there are far too many problems in your program to discuss here. I would suggest revising the whole logic. Remember that array items are numbered from 0 to size-1 (so starting to fill c[i] with i = a does not start from the beginning of the array and will overflow). Also keep in mind what others said about `char msg[] = ""`. Good luck!